# Get total as you type with added column (append) using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="add_supplier">Add Supplier</button>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="supplier_table">
    <thead>
      <tr id="first-header">
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th colspan="2">Supplier</th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="second-header">
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" value="Mouse" readonly=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" value="10" readonly=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="price"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="total"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" value="Keyboard" readonly=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" value="20" readonly=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="price"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="total"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" value="Monitor" readonly=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" value="30" readonly=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="price"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="total"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

This is the add column (append)

```
$(function() {

$('#add_supplier').click(function() {

  $('#supplier_table > thead > tr#first-header').append(
    '<th colspan="2">Supplier</th>'
  );

  $('#supplier_table > thead > tr#second-header').append(
    '<th>Price</th>' +
    '<th>Total</th>'
  );

  $('#supplier_table > tbody > tr').append(
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="price"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="total"></td>'
  );

});

});
```

Demo Link: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jdesparas/ma85eokL/19/)

Comment: Please post a descriptive question with inline image.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Please see the update image. That's what im trying to achieve
The second price column came from append. The first price column works. But in the second column price doesnt.

Comment: Please create a working demo of what you currently have. Your `javascript` variable **vals** means nothing without showing where you declare and assign a value to it. Without the relevant source code it is very hard to offer you any help.

Comment: @JonathanD.Esparas Please create a working snippet or a [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/) Thank you.

Comment: I already added the working snippet. But seems not working. Need help.

Answer (score 0):

One issue if that the newly-added column id's are missing the id number. If you look at the id, it only shows "price-", when it should probably be "price-2-1", since the original ones are "price-1", and the original ones should probably be something like "price-1-1".

Aside from that, the problem is you need to also add the event listeners to the newly-created items:

```
$('#add_supplier').click(function(){

  $('#supplier_table > thead > tr#first-header').append(
      '<th colspan="2">Supplier</th>'
  );

  $('#supplier_table > thead > tr#second-header').append(
      '<th>Price</th>'+
      '<th>Total</th>'
  );

  $('#supplier_table > tbody > tr').append(
      '<td><input type="text" class="form-control price" id="price-"></td>'+
      '<td><input type="text" class="form-control total" id="total-" readonly></td>'
  );



    $(".price").each(function () {
        $(this).keyup(function () {
            multInputs();
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

With the method below you can search the fields according to proximity, thus being able to make the calculations with the necessary parameters.

```js
$(function(){

    $('#add_supplier').click(function(){

      $('#supplier_table > thead > tr#first-header').append(
          '<th colspan="2">Supplier</th>'
      );

      $('#supplier_table > thead > tr#second-header').append(
          '<th>Price</th>'+
          '<th>Total</th>'
      );

      $('#supplier_table > tbody > tr').append(
          '<td><input type="text" class="form-control price" id="price-"></td>'+
          '<td><input type="text" class="form-control total" id="total-" readonly></td>'
      );

    bindPrice();
    
    });
    
    bindPrice();
});

function bindPrice(){

    $('.price').off().on('keyup', function(){
      $total = $(this).parents().eq(0).next().find('.total');
      $qty = $(this).parents().eq(1).find('.qty');
      $total.val($(this).val() * $qty.val() )
    });
   }
```

```html
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #supplier_table thead th,
    td {
      text-align: center;
    }

  </style>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <h2>Bordered Table</h2>
      <p>The .table-bordered class adds borders to a table:</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="add_supplier">Add Supplier</button>
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="supplier_table">
        <thead>
          <tr id="first-header">
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th colspan="2">Supplier</th>
          </tr>
          <tr id="second-header">
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Total</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="tbody-tr">
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" value="Mouse" readonly=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control qty" id="qrt-1" value="10" readonly=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control price" id="price-1"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control total" id="total-1" readonly></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="tbody-tr">
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" value="Keyboard" readonly=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control qty" id="qty-3" value="20" readonly=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control price" id="price-3"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control total" id="total-3" readonly></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="tbody-tr">
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" value="Monitor" readonly=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control qty" id="qty-5" value="30" readonly=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control price" id="price-5"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control total" id="total-5" readonly></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```